# How to start an stop recording sound with one button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, record

Hi I use this HTML code which call JS which records speech and then saves it to my server. I have to click on "start", then click to "stop" recording. I want to make it easier. So user will have to click on button which will have 2 functions "start" and "stop". Can you help me with this issue, because I am new and I don't know how to do that, Thanks

```js
var audio_context;
var recorder;
function startRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.clear(); 
    recorder && recorder.record(); // start recording 
    document.getElementById('uploadBtn').disabled = true; 
    button.disabled = true; //dont allow hit record button during recording 
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
}

function stopRecording(button) {    
    recorder && recorder.stop(); 
    button.disabled = true; 
    button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
    
    createDownloadLink(); 
    document.getElementById('uploadBtn').disabled = false; 
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {  
        uploadAudioFromBlob(blob);
    });
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>   
  <button onclick="startRecording(this);">Start Recording</button>
  <button onclick="stopRecording(this);" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var` a flag to know the current status: idle/recording, change button text and run different function script base on the status.

Comment: @Passerby can you write an example ? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Simply do something like `function toggler(){if(flag){stopRecording();}else{startRecording();}` and assign the button click to this function.